# What is the MYSQL DATE() function doing to my `timeStamp` value?

Tags: mysql

What is the MYSQL DATE() function is doing to my query results? 
Please don't tell me to simply NOT use date().  What is it doing?

I am working with a column `timeStamp` that is a timestamp type field that is auto populated via a default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tableX`;
```

returns a value around 1 million.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tableX` WHERE `timeStamp` BETWEEN "2015-04-01" AND "2015-04-10";
```

returns  388725

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tableX` WHERE Date(`timeStamp`) BETWEEN "2015-04-01" AND "2015-04-10";
```

returns  431925

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `timestamp` has a time component in it and you are using `between`.  That means that anything that occurred on `'2015-04-10'` (after midnight) is being filtered out of the first query -- the time component puts it out of range.

The second version has the time component removed.  So, these match the upper bounds of the range.

Comment: Thanks !  Changing the initial date value in the second query to "2015-04-02" even showed you were correct.  ( Feeling not so smart. )